# Error running Hello world via Docker Toolbox on Windows : "docker daemon is not running"

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I am new to Docker. I installed Docker Toolbox, and have problem running Hello world example like below:

Started Docker QuickStart Terminal with result below:

```
             ##         .
              ## ## ##        ==
           ## ## ## ## ##    ===
       /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
  ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
       \______ o           __/
         \    \         __/
          \____\_______/
Error getting IP address: ssh command error:
command : ip addr show
err : exit status 255
output : Warning: Identity file C:\Users#.lp.docker\machine\machines\default\id_rsa -p 22 "ip addr show" not accessible: No such file or directory.
docker is configured to use the default machine with IP
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com

Start interactive shell

$ docker run hello-world
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.35/containers/create: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.

$ docker --version
Docker version 18.01.0-ce, build 03596f51b1
```

The command below runs forever sometimes,

```
PS C:\Users\'#.lp> docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS
default            virtualbox   Timeout
```

I am trying out Docker Toolbox above, because I cannot run Docker for Windows due to other errors.

Environment:
Windows 10 Pro.

**Updated**
I deleted all VMs from Virtual Box, and open Docker QuickStart Terminal, but it runs forever trying to get IP, like below:

```
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(default) Copying C:\Users\'#.lp\.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso to C:\Users\'#.lp\.docker\machine\machines\default\boot2docker.iso...
(default) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(default) Creating SSH key...
(default) Starting the VM...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Windows might ask for the permission to configure a dhcp server. Sometimes, such confirmation window is minimized in the taskbar.
(default) Waiting for an IP...
```

Comment: what gives docker with "docker-machine ls"?

Comment: Please check my updated post. It runs forever sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
docker-machine ls
```

Probably it's in Timeout state. So stop it with:

```
docker-machine stop dev
```

and close terminal docker windows.
Relaunch Docker Quick Start Terminal again and it should work fine.
Please notice It won't hang but run a little longer then before. I think it might back to normal when you run next time.

This is a known bug with Windows version (which will never be comparable with Linux standard...probably).

If doesn't work, retry this attempt deleting the VM from VBOX after the stop part.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Please check my updated post at the bottom of my post. Error blocked getting IP.

Comment: It's hard to detect from here. Try starting docker terminal after open up VirtualBox, maybe stop temporally the Antivirus, and Firewall.